# Counting algorithm yielding a wrong result

Tags: c

I want a program that counts the number of the votes of the characters R,K,A,T.
When the user types $ it will stop the program.

For instance, I chose R.

I don't know why it yields the correct result minus 1 instead of the correct result. Could somebody please explain this?

The code:

```
#define TAUB_SYMBOL        'T'
#define KARNIN_SYMBOL      'K'
#define RABANI_SYMBOL      'R'
#define APELOIG_SYMBOL     'A'
#define BLANK_VOTE_SYMBOL  'B'
#define CESSATION_SYMBOL   '$'


int main(){
    unsigned int countT=0, countR=0, countK=0, countA=0, countBlank=0;
    unsigned int num; /  /* note that the voter index increases after an invalid votes */
    char vote;
    unsigned int valid_votes=0;
    unsigned int counter=1;
    printf("Election Ballot System\n");
    printf("----------------------\n");

    printf("Ballot secretary, please enter number of registered voters:");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("Voting now commences.\n");

    while(counter<=num){
         printf("Voter %u, indicate your vote and press Enter:",counter);
         scanf("%c\n", &vote);
         if(vote==CESSATION_SYMBOL){
            counter=num+1;
         }
         else{
            switch(vote){

            case RABANI_SYMBOL:
                             countR++;
                        valid_votes++;
                        break;

            case BLANK_VOTE_SYMBOL:
                         countBlank++;
                        valid_votes++;
                        break;
            }
            counter++;
         }
    }

    printf("Voting is concluded.\n");
    printf("Election Results\n");
    printf("%d",countR);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Still not working

Comment: @EladAspis `/` character  after `unsigned int num; /` is it intentional?

Comment: never use scanf to read from keyboard, use fgets and sscanf instead to get better error handling and always check return values of runtime functions that can fail.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this line

```
scanf("%c\n", &vote);
```

To

```
scanf("\n%c", &vote);
```

Since after `num` is inputted you are taking input a `\n` before every input character (R, K, A, T)

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution (not the best for sure):

You can create a new char, e.g. `char temp`, and use to store your `"\n"`

Example:

```
scanf("%d%c",&num,&temp);
```

and

```
scanf("%c%c", &vote,&temp);
```